# Optimize MySQL query "count(*)" with "group by" clause

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, count

I'm using MySQL 5.7, the below sql runs about 10+ seconds, while there are only 60K data totally, and no much columns, i don't why it execute so long time.
To optimize SQL, i add index and update SQL but it didn't work.

Research: when i remove where clause, it runs 400ms, after added it and remove count(*) it also costs 400ms.

```
SELECT adt.data_source_id AS groupName, count(1) AS count
    FROM assets_data_table adt
    WHERE adt.is_deleted = 0
      AND adt.tenant_id = 2
      AND adt.sync_status = 1
    GROUP BY adt.data_source_id;
```

show my table DDL as below:

```
create table assets_data_table
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment comment 'pk'
        primary key,
    create_at datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null comment 'create date',
    update_at datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP comment 'update date',
    create_by int default 0 not null ,
    update_by int default 0 not null ,
    is_deleted tinyint(1) default 0 not null comment '1 deleted，0 undeleted',
    table_name varchar(100) not null ,
    table_name_cn varchar(100) null ,
    data_source_id bigint not null ,
    sync_status tinyint(1) default 0 not null ,
    db_id bigint not null ,
    schema_name varchar(100) null ,
    table_storage bigint default 0 not null ,
    table_owner bigint default 0 not null ,
    table_hot bigint default 0 not null ,
    extra_attribute json null comment 'json string',
    origin_table_id varchar(32) null ,
    tenant_id bigint not null ,
    sync_date datetime null ,
    table_create_at datetime null 
)
comment 'table';
# added to optimize sql
create index assets_data_table_ck
    on assets_data_table (is_deleted, tenant_id, sync_status);
# added to optimize sql
create index assets_data_table_ck_1
    on assets_data_table (is_deleted, tenant_id, sync_status, data_source_id);

create index idx_datasource_id
    on assets_data_table (data_source_id);

create index idx_dbid
    on assets_data_table (db_id);
```

explain:

```
| id | select\_type | table | partitions | type | possible\_keys | key | key\_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| 1 | SIMPLE | adt | NULL | ref | idx\_datasource\_id,assets\_data\_table\_ck,assets\_data\_table\_ck\_1 | assets\_data\_table\_ck\_1 | 10 | const,const,const | 28218 | 100 | Using where; Using index |
```

Attach query result here:
[image]

My optimize:
Using subquery, 1 step: select the needed columns; 2. using group by clause. It can use index and only take 400ms to execute.

```
SELECT adt.data_source_id AS groupName, count(*) AS count
FROM (select is_deleted, tenant_id, sync_status, data_source_id from assets_data_table
      WHERE is_deleted = 0
        AND tenant_id = 2
        AND sync_status = 1) adt
GROUP BY adt.data_source_id;

| id | select\_type | table | partitions | type | possible\_keys | key | key\_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |

| 1 | SIMPLE | assets\_data\_table | NULL | ref | idx\_datasource\_id,assets\_data\_table\_ck,assets\_data\_table\_ck\_1 | assets\_data\_table\_ck\_1 | 10 | const,const,const | 28218 | 100 | Using where; Using index |
```

My question:

1. Is there any alternative way to optimize this query?
2. How group by clause works, and why after i use subquery then it can go through index, can it use index in other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE adt.is_deleted = 0
  AND adt.tenant_id = 2
  AND adt.sync_status = 1
GROUP BY adt.data_source_id;
```

needs a 4-column composite index:

```
 INDEX(is_deleted, tenant_id, sync_status, -- in any order
       data_source_id)   -- last
```

And, since only those 4 columns are used, the index is "covering", thereby making it possibly twice as fast as scaisEdge's Answer.  "Covering" is indicated by "Using index" (not "Using index condition") in `EXPLAIN`.

The nested query suggestion is unlikely to help any.  (There are other situation in which it does help.)

If you have *both*

```
(is_deleted, tenant_id, sync_status)
(is_deleted, tenant_id, sync_status, data_source_id)
```

The first is "redundant".  Also, the Optimizer might mistakenly use the first one when the second would be better.

`BIGINT` is bulky (8 bytes).  Shrinking it may help a little.

Comment: Thanks Rick, as you said, the first index is used and the second is ignored by optimizer, i remove the first one, and then rerun the orignally SQL, the second index is work.

Comment: @KDFinal - Thanks for the feedback.  Do you have a feel for how much faster it works with the 'second' index?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should return  the same value of this

```
select data_source_id, count(*)
from assets_data_table
WHERE is_deleted = 0
AND tenant_id = 2
AND sync_status = 1
group by data_source_id
```

and be sure you  have proper composite index

```
create index  myidx on assets_data_table ( tenant_id , sync_status, is_deleted )
```